# How to set defaults for implicit arguments when they can't be inferred?

Tags: coq, implicit-argument

If I had a module declared as follows in file A.v:

```
Section A.
  Context { : Set}.
  Inductive abt := Abt_leaf (x : ) | Abt_node.
End A.
```

And in another file, B.v, I had:

```
Require Import A.
Definition  := nat.
Inductive typ := Tpe_num | Typ_str.
Definition typ_to_abt (t : typ) : abt (* @abt  *) := Abt_node.
```

The implicit arguments in `abt` when defining `typ_of_abt` can't be inferred.
How could I let Coq know I **always** want `abt` to be `@abt`  in B.v? The intent is to avoid explicitly specifying them using `@`.

Comment: Can you share any concrete example where the problem occurs?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks @Bubbler

Comment: `Let abt := @abt .`?

Comment: @MikeShulman It is a solution. I think `Notation` also works. But both need to be repeated for every definition such as `abt` (when there are many) in A.v. I wonder if there's a more concise solution.

Comment: Ah.  I don't know a better solution in Coq -- I think in Agda you can do that by passing a parameter to a module.  You could conceivably do that in Coq too, but Coq's modules are more heavyweight, and you might run into issues with generativity.

Comment: If you use sections, you can use `#[local] Let …` or `#[local] Notation …` at the beginning of a section, and only repeat it once you close that section and open a new one, which is reasonably economic imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how robust that is, but you can do something quite nice using [typeclasses](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/type-classes.html).

```
Section A.
  Class leaf_type := X : Type.
  Context `{L : leaf_type}.
  Inductive abt := Abt_leaf (x : X) | Abt_node.

End A.

Section B.
  #[local] Instance nat_leaf : leaf_type := nat.

  Inductive typ := Tpe_num | Typ_str.
  Definition typ_to_abt (t : typ) : abt := Abt_node.

End B.
```

To elaborate on what is happening here, we are first declaring a class `leaf_type`, that Coq will try to infer on its own automatically whenever it can, and `abt` makes use of that typeclass. In section B, we put this to work: we declare `nat` as a `#[local]` instance, so that whenever an implicit argument of type `leaf_type` is encountered in that section, Coq will find the local instance `nat` and be happy with it. Once you close the section, the instance is gone and you can declare another one later on.